# Access C# value from HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a variable 'str' defined in C#:

```
 public string str= "hello";
```

I have a HTML file that needs to read the value from 'str'.Im not using ASP.NET. How can I read the value in JavaScript from the HTML file?

Comment: you mean with javascript ?

Comment: What technologies are you using? ASP.NET? Ajax? JavaScript?

Comment: Assuming you are using ASP.NET one of the options would be to write the value into a hidden control then, using either JavaScript `getElementById(elementId)` or jQuery `$("#elementId")` access the control in script.

Comment: what does elementID refer here?

Comment: @user1983100: `elementID` would be what ever the identifier `id` of the hidden control is. Have a look at the [**getElementById - documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) and [**jQuery - documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for more details. Start with either solution and when you get stuck in one, just post the code you are having issues with and we can help you figure it out.

Comment: @user1983100 - if my answer or Abbas's has not helped you here I believe you are using the wrong technologies.  You want to be using ASP.NET with C# to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

If this string, like you mean to say, is defined in a C# file, it means that this variable resides on the server side. Your HTML is client-side, which means that you cannot "just" access this variable. You'll need a connection like a web-service which exposes the variable. This service can then be called through JavaScript. jQuery will be very helpful here.

Another way to access the variable is by putting the value in a hidden field or some other HTML-control. And then with a little piece of JavaScript it's fairly easy to get the value.

**Edit:**
Assuming you're using ASP.NET, following will work:

**C#:**

```
private string str = "Hello World!";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StrHiddenField.Value = str;
}
```

**Page:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="StrHiddenField" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var theValue = document.getElementById('<%=StrHiddenField.ClientID%>').value;
    alert(theValue);
</script>
```

**Edit2:**

Or using jQuery (don't forget to [***download***](http://jquery.com/download/) and include the files)

```
var theValue = $('#<%=StrHiddenField.ClientID%>').val();
```

Comment: can u explain the second way?

Comment: What kind of technology are you using then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `C# MVC`: You can get can assign a hidden for field directly from your model:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.str)
```

Then in your JavaScript file you could do:

```
var str = document.getElementById('str');
```

If you are using `ASP.NET WebForms` you can use a Server Side Control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStr" runat="server" />

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      txtStr.Text = str;
}
```

You would have to inspect the `Document Object Model` to see what this control is called using the Developer Tools in Internet Explorer (`F12`). You could then reference the server side control and assign it to a JavaScript variable using the same approach as I mentioned:  `document.getElementById`